# c++ read object from file with array attribute

Tags: c++, oop

i have a Class and i want to read objects into an array of Objects but i have a problem with an attribute of my class (long data[4];). I don't know how can i read it. In Read Method i want to read all the attributes from file and also create a vector of data elements and append the constructor with that vector witch is read from file.

```
//Class:
class Utilitati{
    const int id;
    float PretUtilitati;
    char * NumeUtilitati;
    int Numarachizitii;
    long data[4];  --This is the problem( I dont know how can i read it )


//Constructor:
    Utilitati(float PretUtilitati, char * NumeUtilitati, int Numarachizitii, long data[]) :id(3){
        this->PretUtilitati = PretUtilitati;
        this->NumeUtilitati = new char[strlen(NumeUtilitati) + 1];
        strcpy(this->NumeUtilitati, NumeUtilitati);
        this->Numarachizitii = Numarachizitii;
        for (int i = 0; i < Numarachizitii; i++)
            this->data[i] = data[i];
    }

Data must be a vector from file.
//Read Method:
void citireFisier(char *numeFisier, Utilitati ** vectUtilitati)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(numeFisier, "r+");
    if (!file)
        cout << "\nEroare citire!" << endl;
    else
    {
        int contor = 0;
        float PretUtilitati;
        char NumeUtilitati[20];
        int Numarachizitii;
        long data[4];

        while (!feof(file))
        {
            fscanf(file, "%f%s%i%l", &PretUtilitati, &NumeUtilitati, &Numarachizitii, &data);
            Utilitati* NewUtilitati = new Utilitati(PretUtilitati, NumeUtilitati, Numarachizitii,data);
            vectUtilitati[contor++] = NewUtilitati;
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
>    The file has the next format: 
>     100   //float PretUtilitati
>     Gaze   //char * NumeUtilitati;
>     3      // int Numarachizitii;
>     20171012  //long data[0];
>     20151012   ////long data[2];
>     20011023   ///long data[Numarachizitii];
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `data` is fixed and always of length 4, you can repeat `%ld` (format specifier for `long`) four times in the `fscanf` pattern.

```
fscanf(file, "%f%s%i%ld%ld%ld%ld",
    &PretUtilitati, &NumeUtilitati, &Numarachizitii,
    &data[0], &data[1], &data[2], &data[3]);
```

And if it's not fixed length, you should first read its length and then using a loop `fscanf` its entries.